# Heatmap with filled and framed overlapping colored rectangles

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to display simple heatmaps with groups framed and filled in a specific color: green, red and black.

I have no problem filling and framing each group by a specific color, there is only one issue here.
When I want to fill and frame a green rectangle, it has to overlapp the red rectangle, resulting into a combination of green and red colors. For a heatmap, this may be an issue because the lightness of each cell is a dimension of the graph. So the red rectangle may visually seem to have more weight than it actually has.

At the very end is the code I am using, I first draw a heatmap (first heatmap) and then I add colored rectangles (both frame and fill addition to the heatmap) as we can see on second heatmap.
We can see the issue of adding green to the red rectangle because on last heatmap, the colors of the red rectangle are much more light.

[image]

I thought about creating 2 green rectangles but we would see twice the green frames.

Do you know any other tip that could avoid this color addition?

```
# 1-Libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

# 2-Simulating data
set.seed(1)
dfHeatmap <- data.frame(a=rep(1:4, times=4), b=rep(1:4, each=4), values=sample(1:100, 16, TRUE))

# 3-Computing Plots
heatmap0color <- ggplot(data=dfHeatmap, aes(x=a, y=b)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=values)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="#4682B4", mid="#d6e1df", high="#6d6d6d", midpoint=1, space="Lab",
                       na.value="grey50", guide="colourbar") + 
  geom_text(aes(label=values)) + 
  theme(legend.position="none", 
        line = element_blank())

heatmap3colors <- ggplot(data=dfHeatmap, aes(x=a, y=b)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=values)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="#4682B4", mid="#d6e1df", high="#6d6d6d", midpoint=1, space="Lab",
                       na.value="grey50", guide="colourbar") + 
  geom_text(aes(label=values)) + 
  theme(legend.position="none", 
        line = element_blank()) +  
  annotate("rect", xmin=0.5, xmax=4.5, ymin=1.5, ymax=4.5, fill="#237551", alpha=0.2, color="#237551") + 
  annotate("rect", xmin=2.5, xmax=4.5, ymin=1.5, ymax=3.5, fill="#ff8e8e", alpha=0.3, color="#ff8e8e") + 
  annotate("rect", xmin=0.5, xmax=4.5, ymin=0.5, ymax=1.5, alpha=0.2, color="black")

heatmap1color <- ggplot(data=dfHeatmap, aes(x=a, y=b)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=values)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="#4682B4", mid="#d6e1df", high="#6d6d6d", midpoint=1, space="Lab",
                       na.value="grey50", guide="colourbar") + 
  geom_text(aes(label=values)) + 
  theme(legend.position="none", 
        line = element_blank()) +  
  annotate("rect", xmin=2.5, xmax=4.5, ymin=1.5, ymax=3.5, fill="#ff8e8e", alpha=0.3, color="#ff8e8e")

# 4-Displaying plots
ggarrange(heatmap0color, 
          heatmap3colors, 
          heatmap1color, 
          nrow=1, ncol=3)
```

Comment: Perhaps you can map `fill` to the green, red and black colors, while using `alpha` to indicate the lightness. Note that green and red will not work for colorblind people.

Comment: Thank you, that's a good idea and you are right about accessibility of colors. Adding two green filled rectangles without frame and a full unfilled rectangle with green frame actually works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the actual solution to avoid having overlapping colors in such heatmaps

```
##### Previous heatmap with overlapping colors (updated alpha value to see difference with solution)
heatmap3colors <- ggplot(data=dfHeatmap, aes(x=a, y=b)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=values)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="#4682B4", mid="#d6e1df", high="#6d6d6d", midpoint=1, space="Lab",
                       na.value="grey50", guide="colourbar") + 
  geom_text(aes(label=values)) + 
  theme(legend.position="none", 
        line = element_blank()) +  
  ggtitle("Previous plots with overlapping colors") + 
  annotate("rect", xmin=0.5, xmax=4.5, ymin=1.5, ymax=4.5, fill="#237551", alpha=0.7, color="#237551") + 
  annotate("rect", xmin=2.5, xmax=4.5, ymin=1.5, ymax=3.5, fill="#ff8e8e", alpha=0.7, color="#ff8e8e") + 
  annotate("rect", xmin=0.5, xmax=4.5, ymin=0.5, ymax=1.5, alpha=0.7, color="black")

##### Heatmap solution (1 unfilled rectangle with frame colored and 2 filled rectangles with frame not-colored)
heatmapSolution <- ggplot(data=dfHeatmap, aes(x=a, y=b)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=values)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="#4682B4", mid="#d6e1df", high="#6d6d6d", midpoint=1, space="Lab",
                       na.value="grey50", guide="colourbar") + 
  geom_text(aes(label=values)) + 
  theme(legend.position="none", 
        line = element_blank()) +  
  ggtitle("Solution") + 
  annotate("rect", xmin=0.5, xmax=4.5, ymin=1.5, ymax=4.5, fill="#237551", alpha=0, color="#237551") + 
  annotate("rect", xmin=0.5, xmax=2.5, ymin=1.5, ymax=4.5, fill="#237551", alpha=0.7) + 
  annotate("rect", xmin=2.5, xmax=4.5, ymin=3.5, ymax=4.5, fill="#237551", alpha=0.7) + 
  annotate("rect", xmin=2.5, xmax=4.5, ymin=1.5, ymax=3.5, fill="#ff8e8e", alpha=0.7, color="#ff8e8e") + 
  annotate("rect", xmin=0.5, xmax=4.5, ymin=0.5, ymax=1.5, alpha=0.7, color="black")

##### Comparison of heatmaps
ggarrange(heatmap3colors, 
          heatmapSolution, 
          nrow=1, ncol=2)
```

[image]